# Tkinter/python: how to create a checkbutton to select all checkbuttons

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I created a list of checkboxes with Tkinter but I would like to select all checkboxes with a single checkbox.

Here is part of my code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SOMETHING")

buttons=[]
#If it is checked, then run the file
def callback():
    for var, name in buttons:
        if var.get():
            subprocess.call("python " + "scripts/" + name)

for name in os.listdir("scripts"):
    if name.endswith('.py') or name.endswith('.pyc'):
        if name not in ("____.py", "_____.pyc"):
            var = tk.BooleanVar()
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=name, variable=var)
            cb.pack()
            buttons.append((var,name))

def select_all():
    if var1.get():
        for i in cb:
            i.select(0,END)

def deselect_all():
    if var2.get():
        for i in cb:
            i.deselect_set(0,END)

var1=tk.BooleanVar()
selectButton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Select All", command=select_all, variable=var1)
selectButton.pack()

var2=tk.BooleanVar()
deselectButton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="None", command=deselect_all, variable=var2)
deselectButton.pack()

submitButton = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=callback)
submitButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the file and press "select all", I get this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'select'.

Please help thanks :)

Comment: What are you expecting ``for i in cb:`` to do?  ``cb`` isn't a list, it is simply the last checkbutton you created.  Also, ``.select(0,END)`` isn't a meaningful operation on a  Checkbutton, that looks like something you'd do to an Entry.  Also also, I don't think BooleanVar is going to work for your checkbuttons - their default on/off states are 1/0, not true/false; try IntVar instead.  Given these vars, the way to select/deselect the buttons is to call ``.set(1)`` or ``.set(0)`` on the vars.

Comment: @jasonharper def select_all() is saying if "select all" checkbox is checked, then go through the list and select all. But I'm not sure what to write for that function. And yeah, I changed BooleanVar to IntVar. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and attached a working tkinter code. Will leave you to resolve the issue with using subprocess.

My main comment is that your use of control variable and how to use it to get and set their value was inappropriate. I have remove the unnecessary codes. Also, shown you how to extract information from your list. Hope this helps your tkinter coding journey.

**Working code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
import os, subprocess

#If it is checked, then run the file
def callback():
    if var.get():
        for i in buttons:
            cmd = "python3 " + filedir +"/" + i[1] #Note:Runs python3 and not python2
            print(cmd)
            subprocess.call(cmd)

def select_all(): # Corrected
    for item in buttons:
        v , n = item
        if v.get():
            v.set(0)
        else:
            v.set(1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("SOMETHING")

filedir = 'test'
buttons=[]

for name in os.listdir(filedir):
    if name.endswith('.py') or name.endswith('.pyc'):
        if name not in ("____.py", "_____.pyc"):
            var = tk.IntVar() 
            var.set(0)
            cb = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=name, variable=var)
            cb.pack()
            buttons.append((var,name))

var1=tk.IntVar()
var1.set(0)
selectButton = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="Select All", command=select_all,
                              variable=var1)
selectButton.pack()

submitButton = tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=callback)
submitButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh But when I click on different checkbox, it clicks everything.

Comment: @RABBIT My bad.. Corrected and uploaded working code.

Comment: couple comments on this. the select all is really a toggle selected. and there was a bug in the callback code. the if should be inside the loop and use i[0].get()  otherwise it's just looking at the value of the last checkbox. I'll fix the code